# Why Dropdown selected values not passing to the backend in jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing

According to this drop down i want to set four conditions in the backend. when i select the dropdown items console will output the values as it is in the code i implemented.but when i debug the program, passed selected value to the backend is **null**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#secquneceDropdownId").change(function() {
    var dropdownSelected = $(this).val();
    console.log('dropdownSelected value is' + dropdownSelected);

    $.post("/IdeaOfThings/listSequences", {
        isDropdownSelected: dropdownSelected,

      },

      function(data, status) {});

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="filter">Type:</label>
<select class="filter" id="secquneceDropdownId">
  <option value="" selected>All</option>
  <option value="INSEQUENCE">In Sequence</option>
  <option value="OUTSEQUENCE">Out Sequence</option>
  <option value="RECIPES">Sequence Mapping</option>
</select>
```

Why selected value printed in console but why it passing a null value to the backend.

Comment: how are you checking int he backend can you share?

Comment: @guradio i just debug the program and check it. is there any problem in above code snappiest? anything wrong in the passing value isDropdownSelected?

Comment: do you have to pass anything after `isDropdownSelected: dropdownSelected,`? @L.Anush

Comment: @Kiranramchandran No i don`t have to pass anything after that.

Comment: @L.Anush then remove , after `isDropdownSelected: dropdownSelected` and try..

Comment: @Kiranramchandran Still the same issue. any other syntax worng?

Comment: @L.Anush any error in developer console?

Comment: @Kiranramchandran in the console value printed out and the following error also their. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

Comment: `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/IdeaOfThings/listSequences',
  data: {isDropdownSelected: dropdownSelected},
  success: success,
  dataType: JSON
});` try this way where dataType is the expected response from the url

Comment: @L.Anush http 405 means  `Method Not Allowed`, there may be any issues in the http header.  try @guardio's comment it will work.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: success is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (listSequences:27002)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: @Kiranramchandran please check .

Comment: @L.Anush change `success:success` to `success:function(data){},`

Comment: @Kiranramchandran Again its POST http://localhost:8080/IdeaOfThings/listSequences 405 (). why this kind of error?

Comment: @L.Anush which server side coding are you using? php or asp.net or any other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183482/discussion-between-l-anush-and-kiranramchandran).

Comment: @Kiranramchandran Spring Boot. Here i`m get the drop down ID value and pass it as a String . if that the case ?